# Solving IVP of a vector field

Tags: dynamical-systems

[image]

I solved the first IVP, $dx/dt = -x$. The solution is $x(t)=pe^{-t}$. Now how should I solve $dy/dt=2y+x^2$. I tried by putting this value of $x(t)$ in $dy/dt$ and tried solving the ODE by finding an integrating factor. Here's what I did:
$$y'(t)=2y(t)+p^2e^{-2t}$$
Using integrating factor, $y(t)=-(p^2/4)e^{-2t}+c/e^{-2t}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. /// For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is an IVP ?

Comment: Initial value problem

Answer (score 1):

No, the solution of the first equation does not have an exponential factor $-2$. It should be $x(t)=pe^{-t}$.

You have to insert the square of $x$, $x(t)^2=p^2e^{-2t}$. Perhaps you did this, but you did not communicate this clearly.

It is possible that the resulting equation for the constant in $y(t)$ reads as $q=y(0)=-\frac14p^2+c$. You should document more steps to let us see if you did it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variation of parameters method: you know the solutions $y_h$ to the homogeneous equation $y_h'-2y_h=0$, then look for a particular solution $y_p = A(t)y_h(t)$ such that $y_p' = 2y_p+pe^{-2t}$.

Solve this for $A(t)$ and add it to $y_h$ and you will have your solution.